# How do I define a function at runtime in python?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, fastapi

I would like to define a function at runtime, without the use of `eval` or `exec`.

Here's what I want:

```py
from typing import Callable, Dict


def create_function(params: Dict) -> Callable:
    func = None
    # Here the code to create func ...
    return func

params = {
    "id": {
        "type": int,
        "default": None
    },
    "name": {
        "type": str,
        "default": None
    },
    "kind": {
        "type": str,
        "default": None
    }
}

my_func = create_function(params)

# my_func would have this signature: my_func(id: int = None, name: str = None, kind: str = None)
```

The reason I want to create functions at runtime is for FastApi.
In FastApi, you use a function as a dependency to have query parameters in your routes. I want to use that feature but the query parameters are defined at runtime, not when I'm writing the code.

Here's a minimal example with functions parameters written in the code directly:

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query

app = FastAPI()


def query_parameters(id: int = Query(None), name: str = Query(None)):
    return {"id": id, "name": name}


@app.get("/hello")
async def get(query_parameters=Depends(query_parameters)):
    return {"message": "hello"}
```

All I want to do is to define `query_parameters` dynamically.

Any ideas ?

Comment: So the created function isn't expected to have a body and should never be called?

Comment: Beyond the signature, what would the body of your function be? This sounds like you're trying to bend FastAPI's magic a little too far though -- consider subclassing APIRoute instead and modifying how it inspects the parameters?

Comment: The function returns the parameters as a dict, as the `query_parameters` function in the example.

Comment: Yes, that could be the solution @AKX